# I want to take comma-separated integers and place them in an array that terminates with a question mark at the end of the array in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, input, integer

C noob here. I'm trying to take in comma-separated integers and place them in an array that terminates with (and contains) a question mark. The input **must** have a comma and yet when I take the input it does not seem to require it. So far I have:

```
    char Array1[100];
    int i;
    do {
        scanf("%d,\n", &Array[i]) {
        i++;
    } while (Array[i] != '?');
}
```

I guess I'm trying to say that I want to make the delimiter (`,`) necessary for every digit input (except the last which must end in a question mark) but `scanf` seems to be brushing right past that requirement.

Comment: `i` has not been initialised, so the behaviour is undefined. But it's a bad idea to have that newline `'\n'` in the `scanf` format string.

Comment: There are plenty of issues in that code. You should always check the return value of `scanf`. Also you pass the address of a single `char` to `scanf` while your format specifier `%d` tells the function to parse an `int` value (and store the corresponding amount of bytes). Furthermore you will never be able to intput a `'?'` while parsing for an integer.

Comment: Besides that your code is a mess. It cannot be compiled. You have missing `;` and extra `{`. Don't show some code you rewrote from mind or maybe completely made up. Show your real code instead. Complete enough to be compilable, and stripped down to be minimal but still showing your problem.

Comment: Will you want the comma there even at the last entry?

Comment: Don't have trailing white-space (like newline) in a `scanf` format string. And *always* check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: @WeatherVane No. I just need every other character to have a comma next to it.

Comment: ....which means you can't insist on the comma after every number.

Comment: Onlyartist9, what should happen if more than 100 numbers are read as `Array1[100]` is only size 100?

Comment: How should `scanf` know your requirements for input format? You have done nothing your code to enforce specific input format.

Comment: `%d` means "scan for an integer". Consequently it requires you to pass a pointer to an integer. Your code pass a pointer to a char.

Comment: Please show a sample input? (Are the integers to be read single digit integers?)

Comment: "I'm trying to take in comma-separated integers and place them in an array that terminates with (and contains) a question mark." I don't understand: you expect that the array *already contains* a question mark *before* you start reading values? If so, where is the code that is supposed to make that happen? Or do you expect to put a question mark into the array *as a result of* reading the integers? In that case, when you read an integer from the user input, how do you ever expect to get a question mark that way? Question marks aren't integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code.

- you do not check for array boundaries: entering more than 100 numbers followed by a comma would cause undefined behavior
- testing `Array[i] != '?'` is wrong on many levels: the character after the number is not stored into the array, numbers are converted so testing for `'?'` means testing if the number happens to be 63, the ASCII code for `?`, and the test uses the next entry in the array which content is uninitialized, invoking undefined behavior too.
- a trailing `\n` in the `scanf` format string will cause `scanf()` to keep reading from the user until a non white space character is read after the `,` consuming and discarding and newlines.

You should use a simpler loop, reading both the number and the separator and test the separator explicitly:

```
    char Array[100];
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    while (i < 100) {
        if (scanf("%d%c", &Array[i], &c) != 2)
            break;
        i++;
        if (c == ',')
            continue;
        if (c == '?')
            break;
        printf("invalid separator: %c\n", c);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine how you have guessed what OP wants the code to do. The description is a complete mess to me.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for. Appreciate the help.